# Angular 5: Show status of GET Http (XHR) request

Tags: angular, get, xmlhttprequest, progress

I have several pages in my app where, depending on user selections, there may be a lot of data to pull back from the server, and I'd like to give a progress indicator. I already have a spinner that works, but if there's a lot of data and/or the connection is slow, then it could take > 30seconds to return all the data, in which case the user doesn't know if the page just froze or not.

Looking at this uploader[example](https://stackblitz.com/angular/yrmnreavrrj), and the [Angular Guide](https://angular.io/guide/http#listening-to-progress-events) got me started on thinking about this, but their example is for a POST when you have a file to upload, and so their messaging revolves around things to do with that file. In my case, it's a GET request, and I'm not sure I changed all the right things, because the `HttpEventType` is apparently only `DownloadProgress` once, so it's not much of a progress.

Has anyone else implemented something like this for GET requests?

```
getData(countryId: string) {
  const req = new HttpRequest('GET', `users?country=${countryId}`, {
    reportProgress: true
  });

  // The `HttpClient.request` API produces a raw event stream
  // which includes start (sent), progress, and response events.
  return this.http.request(req).pipe(
    map(event => this.getEventMessage(event)),
    tap(message => this.showProgress(message)),
    last(), // return last (completed) message to caller
    catchError(this.handleError())
  );
  //the above doesn't seem to be returning the same as this.http.get()
  //but I'm not sure what it needs to be to be equivalent to that
}

/** Return distinct message for sent, upload progress, & response events */
private getEventMessage(event: HttpEvent<any>) {
  switch (event.type) {
    case HttpEventType.Sent:
      return `Downloading data...`;

    case HttpEventType.DownloadProgress:
      // Compute and show the % done:
      event.
      const percentDone = Math.round(100 * event.loaded / event.total);
      return `Downloading data... ${percentDone}% complete.`;

    case HttpEventType.Response:
      return `Data was completely downloaded!`;

    default:
      return `surprising download event: ${event.type}.`;
  }
}

private handleError() {
  const userMessage = `Meh. download failed.`;

  return (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
    // TODO: send the error to remote logging infrastructure
    console.error(error); // log to console instead

    const message =
      error.error instanceof Error
        ? error.error.message
        : `server returned code ${error.status} with body "${error.error}"`;

    this.showProgress(`${userMessage} ${message}`);

    // Let app keep running but indicate failure.
    return of(userMessage);
  };
}

private showProgress(message: string) {
  console.log(message);
}
```